# Why is my Google Font not loading through @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I created font face and applied it to the body:

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Nosifer';
      src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer');  
  }
 body { font-family: 'Nosifer' }
```

```html
<body>
  This is text.
</body>
```

However, the Nosifer font is not visible. What am I doing wrong?

Url to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mr7973y/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome gives the following warning in the console:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer
>
> OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

The Google Fonts implementation guidelines [for this font](https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Nosifer) do not feature the use of `@font-face`. If you want to import it through CSS they advise using `@import` instead:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer');
```

Comment: Thanks. Throught this question I look for the solution of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764887/how-to-load-fonts-automatically-on-the-website?noredirect=1#comment80475104_46764887 if the font faces are the way to say the browser to load fonts.

Answer (score 0):

add this in html header

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer" rel="stylesheet">
```

and apply font like

```
font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
```